# Google Spreadsheet API - POST without Authorization

Tags: post, cordova, google-sheets

I'm trying to HTTP POST to a Google Spreadsheet that is both Published to the Web and the visibility is set that anyone can find and edit. I'm using Postman to make sure my URL works for posting. I've tried using public/basic and private/full. private/full gives me a status of 200 OK and doesn't actually post anything to the spreadsheet. I'm using the correct XML for data as well. I've read on the API that you can do this without authorization but it isn't working for me. I'm not sure where it's failing.

The public/basic version of the url tells me:

```
You do not have add-row access to the spreadsheet. Make sure you are properly authenticated.
```

I'm not sure why though because it is public and published. I've had similar troubles with using Phonegap and using an HTTP GET to get spreadsheet info but that even worked in Postman so I'm unsure what's going on with this.

Any help/direction/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have the Spreadsheet sharing settings set so that Anyone with Link **can edit**?

Comment: Yes. It's available to anyone with the link and anyone can edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think your xml is wrong.

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">
    <gsx:{nameOfHeaderColumn}>contents to display</gsx:{nameOfHeaderColumn}>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've went back to this and it's working using the same requests. I'm unsure of what the exact issue was but it appears to be fixed. I would like to note that POST should only be used with list feeds, for cell based feed posting use PUT.